# iTextSharp edit a PDF, but the cannot see new added objects

Tags: c#, overlay, itext, layer

It seems the PDF file has few layers and I cannot draw new objects overlaying. I have tried to use PDFStamper and GetOverContent() to make the objects topmost, but failed and I don't know why. I just want to add all objects to the top-most layer of the PDF. Is it possible?

How to add all new objects at the top layer of the PDF?

Here is my code:

```
public static bool SaveFile(string srcFile, string DesFile, List<EditPage> pageLs, List<PdfObj> atOtherLs)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcFile);

        Document doc = new Document();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle ps = reader.GetPageSize(i);


            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            EditPage ep = GetEditPage(pageLs, atOtherLs, i - 1);



            WriteEditePage(doc, cb, ps, ep);
        }

        reader.Close();
        doc.Close();

        File.WriteAllBytes(DesFile, ms.ToArray());
        ms.Close();

        return true;
    }


public static void WriteEditePage(Document doc, PdfContentByte cb, Rectangle ps, EditPage ep)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ep.Objs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ep.Objs[i].PdfType != PdfObjTypes.Gdi)
                continue;

            GdiObj gdi = ep.Objs[i] as GdiObj;

            cb.SetColorStroke(new Color(gdi.Color));
            cb.SetColorFill(new Color(gdi.Color));
            cb.SetLineWidth(gdi.Thick / FV);
            if (gdi.Dash != System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid)
            {
                cb.SetLineDash(2, 0.75f);
            }
            else
            {
                cb.SetLineDash(1);
            }

            switch (gdi.GdiType)
            {
                case GdiObjTypes.Points:
                    WritePoints(cb, ps, gdi as GdiPoint);
                    break;
                case GdiObjTypes.Line:
                    WriteLine(cb, ps, gdi as GdiLine);
                    break;
                case GdiObjTypes.Rectangle:
                    WriteRetangle(cb, ps, gdi as GdiRectangle);
                    break;
                case GdiObjTypes.Ellipse:
                    WriteEllipse(cb, ps, gdi as GdiEllipse);
                    break;
                case GdiObjTypes.Image:
                    WriteImage(cb, ps, gdi as GdiImage);
                    break;
                case GdiObjTypes.Text:
                    WriteText(cb, ps, gdi as GdiText);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *PDFStamper and GetOverContent* that would have been more correct than your current code. Please supply a result pdf illustrating the issue for inspection.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong class to add content to an existing PDF document. Please read [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf), more specifically section 6.3.1. Granted, the examples are in Java and you're using iTextSharp, but if you need C# examples, you can always find them on [Sourceforge](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06).

Reading your code sample, I don't have a clue what `GetEditPage()` and `WriteEditPage()` are supposed to do. If the static `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned()` doesn't serve your purpose (e.g. because text isn't wrapped), then you'll need to create a `ColumnText` instance and add the content to that instance.